# Confusion regarding parameters and instance variables

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

In my class players below I have 2 methods. In the method playersFight in my main activity i did, so I am passing in the name fred and bill to my players fight method. I know that you are supposed to the the parameter values to the instance variables such as I did. However If I print player1 and player2 it achieves the same outcome so I am confused as to why we need to set them to the instance variables ??

```
public class GameTime {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Players hockeyPlayer=new Players();
    hockeyPlayer.simpleMessage();
    hockeyPlayer.playersFight("fred", "bill");


  }

}



public class Players {
String name;

int number;
public void simpleMessage(){
System.out.println("This is another Class");
}
public void playersFight(String player1,String player2){
name=player1;
name=player2;
System.out.println(player1+" fights "+player2); 
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to assign the names to 1 instance variable since you're overwriting the 1st assignment. Instance variables are used to keep the information for later. It's still holding the value after your program is done with `playersFight`

Comment: Oh so what would be a good example of a case where instance variables are needed?

Comment: You should think of Java objects as real objects or concepts, where instance variables constitute the state of the object/concept. Your Players class doesn't seem to represent anything concrete. But you might imagine a CasinoRoom, containing a list of GameTable, where each GameTable would have two Players, and each Player would have a name and a score. You could then ask each GameTable who is the winner of the two players. You could ask the CasinoRoom the name of the Player which has the best score. etc. All these questions you ask to objects are methods, that information from the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from just your code and brief description, you are not using the 'name' instance variable. Therefore, you can remove it and the two lines:

```
name = player1;
name = player2;
```

However, this is only if you are just using the print statement at the end of your 'playersFight' method.

It appears to me (correct me if I'm wrong), that you want to use the 'playersFight' method to print out "fred fights bill." It also seems that you are wanting to reprint that message later, thus you have a 'name' instance variable that should be equal to that statement, "fred fights bill," so that you can reuse that string concatenation later without reentering your variables as parameters

In that case your code is wrong as you are setting name to player one and then reassigning it to player2. What you should do is change this:

```
name = player1;
name = player2;
```

into this:

```
name = player1 + "fights" + player2;
```

and have your System.out be:

```
System.out.println(name);
```

The reason you use the instance variable is so that you can keep that name and print it as many times as you want in any function you want without retaking the parameters. Really, the best way to do this would be to take the names from the first time you instantiate your 'Player' object. To do this you would need a constructor that inputs the names. You will also probably want to change the names later and thus need a change names method (that works like the constructor). Also, you'll since you won't be calling the name and number variables outside their class, you should make them public. These changes would follow like this:

```
public class GameTime {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        // First players "Fred" and "Bill"
        Players hockeyPlayer = new Players("fred", "bill");
        hockeyPlayer.simpleMessage();
        hockeyPlayer.playersFight();

        // New players "Amy" and "Sam"
        hockeyPlayers.changePlayers("amy", "sam");
        hockeyPlayer.simpleMessage();
        hockeyPlayer.playersFight();
    }
}

public class Players {
    private String name;
    private int number;

    public Players(String player1, String player2) {
        name = player1 + " fights " player2;
    }

    public void changePlayers(String player1, String player2) {
        name = player1 + " fights " player2;
    }

    public void simpleMessage(){
        System.out.println("This is another Class");
    }

    public void playersFight() {
        System.out.println(name); 
    }
}
```